# Why do I get none displayed when I write and then print using if statement in python that does simple computation?

Tags: python, if-statement

Trying to write a function that calculates the ground cost of shipping a product based on its weight.

```
def ground_cost(weight):
  if weight<=2:
    price= 1.5*weight + 20
  elif  (weight>2) and (weight<=6):
    price=3*weight + 20
  elif (weight>6) and (weight<=10):
    price=4*weight + 20
  else:
    price=4.7*weight + 20
    return price

print(ground_cost(8.4))
```

I used simple if and elif statements to do this but getting NONE displayed every time.

I expected output to be 53.6 but it is showing none.

Comment: BTW, you don't need some of the conditions. `elif  (weight>2) and (weight<=6):` could just be `elif weight <= 6:`. The case where `weight` is not greater than `2` is already handled in the previous condition.

Answer (score 1):

Your return statement is embedded in the final `else` clause, it needs to be at the same indentation as your initial `if`.  In your code example this is never reached and thus the function returns the default of `None` since no return statement is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Indent your return statement properly:

```
def ground_cost(weight):
  if weight<=2:
    price= 1.5*weight + 20
  elif  (weight>2) and (weight<=6):
    price=3*weight + 20
  elif (weight>6) and (weight<=10):
    price=4*weight + 20
  else:
    price=4.7*weight + 20
  return price

print(ground_cost(8.4))
```